# How to parse JSon in Pure Batch

Tags: json, parsing, batch-file, for-loop, token

I am trying to understand how for loops in batch files can iterate through all items with the /F "delims=" option but without tokens.  I have tried various ways but failed.  First off I know there are other ways to read json files but I'm only interested in learning how to do it in pure batch without any external programs jscript jq etc. The JSon format is as shown below but the number of items and the order they are in tend to vary.

```
{"SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString"}
{"SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString"}
{"SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString"}
{"SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString", "SomeVariableName": "SomeString"}
etc
```

But sometimes it could just be:

```
"SomeVariableName2": "SomeString2", "SomeVariableName1": "SomeString1",
```

for example I have so for done:

```
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "delims=" %%c (file.json) Do(
REM iterate through each line
  set "Line=%%c"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set CR=CRLFCRLF
  Set "LineChange1=!Line:~1,-1!"
  for %%d in ("!CR!") do set LineChange2=!LineChange1:", "=%%~d!
  for %%e in (!LineChange4:CRLFCRLF= !) do set /a numtkns+=1
  REM but don't know how to insert the above numtkns in for options as it seems to require a function.
  set LineChange3=!LineChange2:": "==!
  set LineChange4=!LineChange3:"=!
  set /A Countr+=1
  REM this leaves this current line stored in variable LineChange4 as SomeVariableName=SomeStringCRLFCRLFSomeVariableName=SomeStringCRLFCRLFSomeVariableName=SomeStringCRLFCRLFSomeVariableName=SomeString
  )
```

alternatively I could use newlines instead of CRLFCRLF:

```
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "delims=" %%c (file.json) Do(
REM iterate through each line
set "Line=%%c"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%d in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do (
 set "CR=%%d"
)
Set "LineChange1=!Line:~1,-1!"
for %%e in ("!CR!") do set LineChange2=!LineChange1:", "=%%~e!
set LineChange3=!LineChange2:": "==!
set LineChange4=!LineChange3:"=!
set /A Countr+=1

)
```

This results in a multi-line stored in variable LineChange4:

```
SomeVariableName=SomeString
SomeVariableName=SomeString
SomeVariableName=SomeString
SomeVariableName=SomeString
```

How do I iterate through each key value pair and assign each value to a variable of the same name as the key. I have seen another post where they did set var_%SomeVariableName%=SomeString  but it only works for the first key value pair and I want it to iterate through all the items until the last one even if the number of tokens and their order vary.

Edit:The SomeString may be a title with various characters so the only approximately known values are the SomeVariableName keys which tend to not have spaces.

Edit2: I did not originally add that I also used "Set "LineChange1=!Line:~1,-1!" to removes the curly braces which usually come with JSon files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another, simpler approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read the lines of JSon file, removing braces
for /F "delims={}" %%a in (file.json) do (
   set "line=%%~a"
   rem Process each pair of "variable": "string" values
   for %%b in ("!line:": "==!") do echo SET %%b
)
```

Using this input file:

```
{"SomeVariableName1": "Some String 1", "SomeVariableName2": "Some&String<2", "SomeVariableName3": "Some>String|3", "SomeVariableName4": "Some  String  4"}
{"SomeVariableName1": "SomeString1", "SomeVariableName2": "SomeString2", "SomeVariableName3": "SomeString3", "SomeVariableName4": "SomeString4"}
{"SomeVariableName1": "SomeString1", "SomeVariableName2": "SomeString2", "SomeVariableName3": "SomeString3", "SomeVariableName4": "SomeString4"}
{"SomeVariableName1": "SomeString1", "SomeVariableName2": "SomeString2", "SomeVariableName3": "SomeString3", "SomeVariableName4": "SomeString4"}
```

... this is the output:

```
SET "SomeVariableName1=Some String 1"
SET "SomeVariableName2=Some&String<2"
SET "SomeVariableName3=Some>String|3"
SET "SomeVariableName4=Some  String  4"
SET "SomeVariableName1=SomeString1"
SET "SomeVariableName2=SomeString2"
SET "SomeVariableName3=SomeString3"
SET "SomeVariableName4=SomeString4"
SET "SomeVariableName1=SomeString1"
SET "SomeVariableName2=SomeString2"
SET "SomeVariableName3=SomeString3"
SET "SomeVariableName4=SomeString4"
SET "SomeVariableName1=SomeString1"
SET "SomeVariableName2=SomeString2"
SET "SomeVariableName3=SomeString3"
SET "SomeVariableName4=SomeString4"
```

Comment: Nice one! though it does not allow `{` and `}` to appear in any of the names/strings; +1 anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Given that both the key (`SomeVariableName`) and the value (`SomeString`) parts of your input string do not contain `*`, `?`, `<`, `>`, `"`, they are really enclosed within quotation marks `""`, the key part (`SomeVariableName`) does not contain `:`, `=`, and the value part (`SomeString`) does not equal the sequence `:` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, the following could work:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Read JSON file line by line:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("file.json") do (
    rem // Store current line string:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Replace key/value separator `": "` by `":"` (remove space):
    set "LINE=!LINE:": "=":"!"
    rem // Trim off opening and closing braces `{`/`}`:
    if defined LINE if "!LINE:~,1!"=="{" set "LINE=!LINE:~1!"
    if defined LINE if "!LINE:~-1!"=="}" set "LINE=!LINE:~,-1!"
    rem // Iterate through key/value pairs (separated by `, `):
    for %%P in (!LINE!) do (
        endlocal
        rem // Split key/value pair:
        for /F "tokens=1* delims=: eol=:" %%Q in ("%%P") do (
            rem // Remove quotes, assign variable (key = value):
            set "%%~Q=%%~R"
        )
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    endlocal
)
```

This approach changes every key/value pair `"SomeVariableName": "SomeString"` by removing the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> behind the separating colon `:`; since the `:` is not a standard token separator, opposed to <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and comma `,`, a standard [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) can iterate though every key/value pair as a single item; a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) can then be used to split key and value at the `:`; finally, the surrounding quotation marks `""` of each part becomes removed by the [`~` modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and the assignment is done.

Toggling [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is done in order not to have troubles with exclamation marks `!` appearing in the input strings.

Comment: Actually the SomeString may be a title with various characters so the only approximately known values are the SomeVariableName keys which tend to not have spaces. I've updated my question, apologies for forgetting to add that.

Comment: Both `SomeVariableName` and `SomeString` may contain spaces; the most recent edit even allows the sequence colon followed by space...

Answer (score 1):

Where file.json or data being downloaded is in the format below

```
{"SomeVariableName1": "SomeString1", "SomeVariableName2": "SomeString2", "SomeVariableName3": "SomeString3", "SomeVariableName4": "SomeString4"}
{"SomeVariableName1": "SomeString1", "SomeVariableName2": "SomeString2", "SomeVariableName3": "SomeString3", "SomeVariableName4": "SomeString4"}
{"SomeVariableName1": "SomeString1", "SomeVariableName2": "SomeString2", "SomeVariableName3": "SomeString3", "SomeVariableName4": "SomeString4"}
{"SomeVariableName1": "SomeString1", "SomeVariableName2": "SomeString2", "SomeVariableName3": "SomeString3", "SomeVariableName4": "SomeString4"}
```

The below code works as per the modified code from the answer by aschipfl even if the SomeString contains spaces.

```
:: Define a TAB variable
For /F "delims=" %%A In ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x09"') Do Set "TAB=%%A"

rem // also works for ('something that downloads json content')
For /F "delims=" %%c In ('file.json') Do (
    REM // Store current line string:
    Set "LINE=%%c"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    REM // Replace beginning and ending curly brackets:
    Set "LineChange1=!Line:~1,-1!"
    REM // Replace key/value separator ": " by ":" (remove space):
    Set "LineChange2=!LineChange1:": "=":"!"
    REM // Replace CSV ", " with TSV "TAB" (remove space):
    Set "LineChange3=!LineChange2:", "="%TAB%"!"
    REM // Iterate through key/value pairs (separated by Tab):
    For %%P In (!LineChange3!) Do (
        EndLocal
        REM // Split key/value pair:
        For /F "tokens=1* delims=: eol=:" %%Q In ("%%P") Do (
            REM // Remove quotes, assign variable (key = value):
            Set "var_%%~Q=%%~R"
        )
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
@Echo SomeVariableName1=!var_SomeVariableName1!>>Datafile.txt
@Echo SomeVariableName3=!var_SomeVariableName3!>>Datafile.txt
)
```

Comment: Replacing `,`+SPACE by TAB should not be necessary, since SPACE, TAB, `,`, as well as `;`, `=`, are equivalent token separators... And the braces should already have been mentioned in the question...

Comment: Yeah, I was so tired when I posted the question after spending so much time trying to figure it out that I just posted it that way as that wasn't really my main concern.  I'm not sure why the code as you posted it did not work as is but it did after replacing with a tab. I'm new to batch and so I'll leave it up to someone else to figure out why and leave this post in case someone can benefit from it.  If you want to test it with the type of json file I was dealing with you can get it from the youtube-dl cli with --dump-json.  Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vasil Arnaudov's script
https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/edit.json.bat
you can edit multi-level JSON:

normal.json:

```json
{ "solo": "Solo value", "level1": { "name": "Name1", "version": "04.21", "level2": { "name": "Name2", "code": "da" } }, "single": "Single value" }
```

Running:

```
edit.json.bat normal.json level1.level2.name "name of level 2"
```

will give you:

```json
{"solo":"Solo value","level1":{"name":"Name1","version":"04.21","level2":{"name":"name of level 2","code":"da"}},"single":"Single value"}
```